# Dreamweaver / Filezilla / other FTP Client - summary of connections and edited files

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, filezilla

is it somehow possible to get a summary of connections and edited files? Currently im using Dreamweaver and Filezilla, but i havent found a possibility to solve this.
Perfect would be something like :

```
13:40:12 - connected to SERVER1
13:40:50 - uploaded "test.php" to "/path/to/dir"
13:41:02 - opened file "file.php"
13:41:40 - uploaded edited version of "file.php"
```

... and so on

I need this to overview my hours of work, for something like timekeeping and to know afterwards which files ive edited for documentation reasons.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use FileZilla, simply enable file logging.

Open `Edit` then `Settings…` in menubar. Next, select page `Logging` in the left handed settings tree. On the right side you should tick `Show timestamps in message log` and `Log to file`. Enter a `Filename` you like to log that information to and restart FileZilla. Just keep in mind that you manually should remove the file from time to time as it will grow.

If you want to use the FTP functionality from within Dreamweaver, simply use an FTP proxy.

You basically download an FTP proxy of your choice and install it locally. You then enable logging in the FTP proxy and connect from Dreamweaver though your FTP proxy to the client's server. The proxy will log all actions and you can then use the time information for book keeping.